# "Segmentation fault (core dumped)" when trying to set a Qpixmap to Qlabel when image comes from Pillow

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt4, python-imaging-library

so I'm trying to display an image onto my UI. The way i found of doing so is by setting a QPixmap to Qlabel.

```
qimg = QtGui.QImage("Lenna.png") # load QImage
pixImg = QtGui.QPixmap().fromImage(qimg) # convert QImage to QPixmap
self.imgLabel.setPixmap(pixImg) # add the QPixmap picture to GUI
```

This works perfectly fine, the issue comes when I use Pillow to get the QImage `qimg = PIL.Image.open("Lenna.png").toqimage()`, thats when I get segfault. I've tried casting whatever pillow is giving me into QImage, but that doesn't solve anything and I couldn't find anything else that could be somewhat relevant

Comment: You need to keep a reference to the pil image object.

Comment: i've tried that. Putting everything into a variable of its own, I've tried using Pillow's provided ImageQT class instead of `Image.toqimage()` that i digged out from the source code, even tried going over core dump to no avail

Comment: A variable is not enough (depending on how you do it). Please provide a [mcve], which shows exactly what you've tried.

Comment: Which is exactly what I've provided (or so I would like to think). PIL image -> QT Qimage -> QPixmap, and during attempted `Qlable.setPixmap(img)` I get segfault. The only logical conclusion that i was able to come up with is that something goes wrong during type conversions, not noticable enough to rise an exception, but enough for the underlying QT layer to break

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`PIL.ImageQt` has a very neat, `toqpixmap(img)` method, which for some reason isn't on the documentations. So instead of doing a long-winded conversion (which at the time, i thought was the only way), I'm able to just do

```py
img = Image.open("Lenna.png")
pixImg = ImageQt.toqpixmap(img)
self.imgLabel.setPixmap(pixImg)
```

which seem to work perfectly fine